# Function to coerce strings given a condition

Tags: r, where-clause, dplyr, coercion, across

I simply want to coerce as numbers --i.e., to apply `as.numeric` to--any columns which have a `1` as their first entry (i.e., a character).  So I would expect to turn:

```
tibble(a = c("1", "2"), b = c("Fred", "Kevin"), c = 1:2)
```

into

```
tibble(a = 1:2, b = c("Fred", "Kevin"), c = 1:2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  mutate(across(where(~ first(.x) == "1" & !is.na(first(.x))), as.numeric)).
```

returns

```r
# A tibble: 2 x 5
      a b         c     d e    
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>
1     1 Fred      1     1 NA    
2     2 Kevin     2     3 NA
```

### Data

```r
data <- tibble(a = c("1", "2"), 
               b = c("Fred", "Kevin"), 
               c = 1:2, 
               d = c("1", "3"), 
               e = c(NA, NA))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  One snag--which I have in fact realised was my problem in the first place:  when some of the values are NA, it errors.  For instance, set the last column to e = c(NA, NA), and an error arises.  Any ideas on how to fix it?  Many thanks for the reply!  James.

Comment: You could try `mutate(across(where(~ first(.x) == "1" & !is.na(first(.x))), as.numeric))`.

Comment: Thanks Martin.  That's done the job.  Appreciate the help.  James.

Answer (score 1):

It's not doing strictly whate you asked for, but you could use readr's `guess_parser` or `parse_guess` functions. See https://readr.tidyverse.org/reference/parse_guess.html for more details.

In your case you could do:

```
df %>% mutate(across(everything(),parse_guess))
```

Which would parse all columns. Or for just parsing if the column is going to numeric:

```
parse_guess_numeric <- function (x){
    if (guess_parser(x, guess_integer=FALSE)=="double"){
        as.numeric(x)
    } else {
        x
    }

}

df %>% mutate(across(everything(),parse_guess_numeric))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to approach this: use `type.convert` or `type_convert` from `readr`:

```
type.convert(df, as.is = TRUE)
# A tibble: 2 x 3
      a b         c
  <int> <chr> <int>
1     1 Fred      1
2     2 Kevin     2


readr::type_convert(df)

-- Column specification ---------------------------------------------------------------------
cols(
  a = col_double(),
  b = col_character()
)

# A tibble: 2 x 3
      a b         c
  <dbl> <chr> <int>
1     1 Fred      1
2     2 Kevin     2
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(a = c("1", "2"), b = c("Fred", "Kevin"), c = 1:2, d = c(NA, NA))
fltr <- names(df)[map_chr(df, guess_parser) == "double"]
mutate(df, across(all_of(fltr), as.numeric))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>       a b         c d    
#>   <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <lgl>
#> 1     1 Fred      1 NA   
#> 2     2 Kevin     2 NA
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>